# UIPageControl customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to make something like `UIPageViewController` where I can swipe between different VC's. But instead of custom dot control I need to have custom buttons. So that either user can select different VC with button click or can swipe.

Right now I'm using `UIScrollView` to make this. I don't know how to proceed with buttons so I need help with that.

Is there any custom control that'll be useful for this?

Comment: check out [ICViewPager](https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in different ways. If you have three pages, you can create a UI with three buttons(or a tab bar) and in the action you can call:

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndex:YourPageIndex]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
```

`UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse` or `UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward` can be used as required.

This is how we do it.

Or you can use any custom libraries:
[Carbon kit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit) is a working library. [Here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=pageviewcontroller) you can find many of them.

OR TRY THIS( [a simpler example on carbon kit](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/CCkitTest-iOS) )

Comment: Thanks :) that helped a lot